# Draw icons inside Gantt chart Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, gantt-chart

Is it possible to draw icons (for Milestones and so forth) inside a `Gantt` chart in Tableau? I've been struggling with it for a week and I came to no conclusion about it, even researching about likely tricks like placeholders.

I've found no example nor PoC about it, so maybe someone with further experience or bases in Tableau can tell me if it's possible.

Version: 2019.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a crude example of this on Tableau's site a few years ago. Hope it helps.

https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-5521

I think it could be formatted better, but should show you the basics.

Comment: Thank you so much! Completely valid, I hope I can adapt it to my needs!